# how to change the text of a element and add atribute in another element after a match with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have to add an attribute on a specific element after a match, and also change the text of another element, I don't understand how I can move between elements after the match and I need some help.

I have this XML as input:

```
<start>
   <transfers>
       <transfer position="E2">
           <branch name="2025_1ZTE">
               <code>DKU</code>
               <place>office</place>
           </branch>
       </transfer>
       <transfer position="E3">
           <branch name="1522_5MCO">
               <code>TSM</code>
               <place>office</place>
           </branch>
       </transfer>
       <transfer position="E4">
           <branch name="4852_3MCO">
               <code>WTD</code>
               <place>factory</place>
           </branch>
       </transfer>
   </transfers>
</start>
```

When I match the place office and the last 3 characters of the attribute name is MCO, I need to copy all the node and add a new atributte in the element branch, and change office by  teleworking, my xslt already match what I want but it add the attribute into the wrong element, because it add the attribute in transfer and not branch, and also I try to change the text of the element place but It does not change.

If the node does not match, I just need to copy it.

I need an output like :

```
<start>
   <transfers>
       <transfer position="E2">
           <branch name="2025_1ZTE">
               <code>DKU</code>
               <place>office</place>
           </branch>
       </transfer>
       <transfer position="E3">
           <branch name="1522_5MCO" agreed="yes">
               <code>TSM</code>
               <place>teleworking</place>
           </branch>
       </transfer>
       <transfer position="E4">
           <branch name="4852_3MCO">
               <code>WTD</code>
               <place>factory</place>
           </branch>
       </transfer>
   </transfers>
</start>
```

This is the XSLT that I have :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="transfer[branch[place/text()='office'][@name[substring(., string-length(.) - 2) ='MCO']]]">
 <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
   <xsl:attribute name="agreed">yes</xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:param name="place" select="'teleworking'"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="branch[place='office' and substring(@name, string-length(@name) - 2) ='MCO']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="agreed">yes</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:copy-of select="code"/>
        <place>teleworking</place>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```